# How do I resolve: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, string

The issue occurs on **line 70** - The function is `def test()`.

`if sum(characters) > [1]: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`

For reference, this is a password strength checker.

How do I go about solving this? It seems like the code executes and can count the length of the input as well as add points to the score

```
import sys
import time
import random
import string  # check for certain characters


def ten():
    length = 10
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'

    rnd = random.SystemRandom()
    print(''.join(rnd.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))


def fifteen():
    length = 15
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'

    rnd = random.SystemRandom()
    print(''.join(rnd.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))


def twenty():
    length = 20
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'

    rnd = random.SystemRandom()
    print(''.join(rnd.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))


def twentyfive():
    length = 25
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'

    rnd = random.SystemRandom()
    print(''.join(rnd.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))


def test():
    # Password Checker

    option = input()

    upper_case = ([1 if c in string.ascii_uppercase else 0 for c in option])
    lower_case = ([1 if c in string.ascii_lowercase else 0 for c in option])
    special = ([1 if c in string.punctuation else 0 for c in option])
    digits = ([1 if c in string.digits else 0 for c in option])

    characters = [upper_case, lower_case, special, digits]
    length = len(option)
    score = 0

    if length > 8:
        score += 1
    if length > 12:
        score += 1
    if length > 13:
        score += 1
    if length > 15:
        score += 1
    if length > 16:
        score += 1
    if length > 20:
        score += 1
    if length > 25:
        score += 1

    print(f"Password length is {str(length)}, adding {str(score)} points!")

    if sum(characters) > 1:
        score += 1
    if sum(characters) > 2:
        score += 1
    if sum(characters) > 3:
        score += 1

    print(f"Password has {str(sum(characters))} different character types, adding {str(sum(characters) - 1)} points! ")

    if score < 4:
        print(f"Week {str(score)} / 7")
    elif score == 4:
        print(f"Week {str(score)} / 7")
    elif 4 < score < 6:
        print(f"Week {str(score)} / 7")
    elif score > 6:
        print(f"Week {str(score)} / 7")


def quit():
    print("This program will now exit...")
    time.sleep(2)
    sys.exit()


# This is the menu function

def menu():
    print("Hello Welcome To My Password Generator!!!")
    time.sleep(1)

    option = input("""
    
                        1: Generate a Random 10 Character Password
                        2: Generate a Random 15 Character Password
                        3: Generate a Random 20 Character Password
                        4: Generate a Random 25 Character Password
                        5: Test Password Strength
                        Q: Quit
                        
                        Please decide on an option from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or Q:
                        
    """)

    if option == "1":
        ten()
    elif option == "2":
        fifteen()
    elif option == "3":
        twenty()
    elif option == "4":
        twentyfive()
    elif option == "5":
        test()
    elif option == "Q" or option == "q":
        quit()
    else:
        print("Error, you must enter a valid choice from the above menu")
        menu()


menu()
```

Comment: Do not have functions called `ten` and `fifteen` and `twenty` and `twentyfive`.  Just have one function called `generate` and pass the length as a parameter.

Comment: And what's the point of the `if score < 4:` section?  You're printing the same string each time.  Also note that an "f" string knows how to handle integers.  You never need to call `str` inside an f-string format.  Just do `f"Week {score} / 7"`.

Comment: @Claudio: Oddly, the posted code doesn't have those brackets, so it shouldn't error like that. OP: You need to post the code that actually reproduces your problem.

Comment: That error can't be because of the `[1]` -- the error says the problem is with `+`, not `>`.

Answer (score 1):

I've redone your file to get rid of the unnecessary function calls, to eliminate the silly recursion, and to check the character classes in a better way.  This does what you want, I believe.

```
import sys
import random
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'

def generate(length):
    print(''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for i in range(length)))

def test():
    # Password Checker

    option = input()

    upper_case = any(c in string.ascii_uppercase for c in option)
    lower_case = any(c in string.ascii_lowercase for c in option)
    special = any(c in string.punctuation for c in option)
    digits = any(c in string.digits for c in option)

    length = len(option)
    score = 0

    for k in [8,12,13,15,16,20,25]:
        if length < k:
            break
        score += 1

    print(f"Password length is {length}, adding {score} points!")

    characters = sum([upper_case, lower_case, special, digits])
    score += characters - 1

    print(f"Password has {characters} different character types, adding {characters-1} points! ")

    if score < 4:
        print(f"Weak {score} / 7")
    elif score < 5:
        print(f"OK {score} / 7")
    elif score < 6:
        print(f"Medium {score} / 7")
    else:
        print(f"Strong {score} / 7")


# This is the menu function

def menu():
    print("Hello Welcome To My Password Generator!!!")

    while True:
        option = input("""
                            1: Generate a Random 10 Character Password
                            2: Generate a Random 15 Character Password
                            3: Generate a Random 20 Character Password
                            4: Generate a Random 25 Character Password
                            5: Test Password Strength
                            Q: Quit
                            
                            Please decide on an option from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or Q:
        """)

        if option == "1":
            generate(10)
        elif option == "2":
            generate(15)
        elif option == "3":
            generate(20)
        elif option == "4":
            generate(25)
        elif option == "5":
            test()
        elif option in "Qq":
            break
        else:
            print("Error, you must enter a valid choice from the above menu")

menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
characters = [upper_case, lower_case, special, digits]
```

creates a list of lists. `sum(characters)` won't work because that tries to add the lists to `0` to get the total, and you can't add a list to a number.

You should use

```
characters = upper_case + lower_case + special + digits
```

to concatenate all the lists instead of making nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with the original posted code, I was missing the any() function.

```
upper_case = any([1 if c in string.ascii_uppercase else 0 for c in option])
lower_case = any([1 if c in string.ascii_lowercase else 0 for c in option])
special = any([1 if c in string.punctuation else 0 for c in option])
digits = any([1 if c in string.digits else 0 for c in option])
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please, next time you ask a question add an explanation to the code of what it does to save people time here trying to help you!
[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)